# Is the following continuously differentiable function uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

This particular question was asked in my real analysis quiz and my answers in it were not correct . So, I am asking them here .

> Question: Let f be continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ . Let $f_n(x)=n (f(x+1/n)-f(x))$ . Then ,

1. $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ .
2. $f_n$ converges on $\mathbb{R}$ , but not necessarily uniformly .
3. $f_n$ converges to the derivative of f uniformly on [0,1] .

4.there is no guarantee that $f_n$ converges on any open interval .

Attempt: Continuity of $f_n$ implies that $f(x+1/n)-f(x) < \frac {\epsilon} {n}$  .  So, $f_n \to 0  $
as  $ n\to \infty$ . Also , convergence must be uniform by using defination of uniform convergence.So, (a) is correct ,(b) is wrong.

Derivative of 0 =0 . So, (c) is correct . (d) is wrong .

But answers given in answer key are different .

> Answer:

> 2,3

So , It is my humble request to tell me what mistake I am making and how to proceed to correct answer.

Comment: Why does continuity of $f_n$ implies what you wrote? A continuous function not necessarily satisfy the inequality you wrote. Also the derivative of a general continuously differentiable function doesn't have to be identically $0$, which seems to be implied by what you wrote.

Comment: How about $f(x)=x^3$ . Then $f_n(x)-f'(x)=\frac 1{n^2}+\frac {3x}n $ and so for $x_n=n $ . we have $f_n(x_n)-f'(x_n) \gt 3$ showing non-uniform convergence of $f_n$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user710290 you are taking $f_n(x)−f′(x)$ but question talks about $f_n(x)−f(x)$.

Comment: The limit function of the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is $f'(x)$ . That's why I am talking about $f_n(x)-f'(x)$ . I do not agree with what you said.

Comment: @user710290 got it !! So, 1,2 are sorted out .Can you please also help with (3) and (4)?

Comment: @Tim  I have written an answer  instead of a long comment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that $f_n (x) \to f'(x) $ as $n\to \infty$

For $(1)$ and $(2)$ take $f(x)=x^3$ and show the non-uniform convergence of $f_n$ on $\mathbb{R}$ .

For $(3)$

Claim:  $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on $[0,1]$

Proof : Note that $f$ is continously differentiable, i.e $f'$ is continous .

Since continous function on a compact set is uniformly continous , so $f'$ is uniformly continous on $[0,1]$.

So given $\epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0$   such that $\forall x,y\in [0,1]$ with $|x-y| \lt \delta$ , we have $|f'(x)-f'(y)| \lt \epsilon $

By Archimedan Property of Real Numbers , there exist $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\forall n\gt N$ , have $\frac 1n \lt \delta$

Now ,let $x\in [0,1]$ be arbitary  and $n\gt N$

Then , $f(x+\frac 1n)-f(x)=\frac 1n f'(a)$   for some $x \lt a \lt x+\frac 1n$, by Mean Value Theorem

Thus $| f_n(x)-f'(x)|=|f'(a)-f'(x)|\lt \epsilon $ since $|x-a| \lt \frac 1n \lt \delta$

Thus the claim is proved.

$(4)$ is obviously false since the sequence always converges pointwise to the derivative, whatever be the domain.